# Google Fusion Table Map export static HTML

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I'm a little confused with the Google Fusion Tables map. I made the underlying table shared with the Public Internet. Then I clicked share and Copied the Raw HTML. I made a few updates to add a Legend. It's perfectly viewable in my browser, when I click the HTML file, on my Laptop. Yet, on my Android phone, when I open the HTML, it crashes as soon as I try to move the map; further, it is too zoomed-in on the Android phone. 
Do I need to host this somewhere for others to see it? Or is sending them a Raw HTML file and making the underlying Fusion Table shareable, enough, for anyone to click the HTML and view an interactive Map? What adjustments need to be made for mobile browsers?
Thanks and here's my code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport"></meta>
<title>IDOT Crash Data--Park Ridge</title>

<link href="/apis/fusiontables/docs/samples/style/default.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>

<style type="text/css">
      html, body, #googft-mapCanvas{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
      #legend {
        background: #FFF;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 5px;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      }
      .color {
        border: 1px solid;
        height: 12px;
        width: 12px;
        margin-right: 3px;
        float: left;
      }
      .green {
        background: #6F0;
      }

      .blue {
        background: #06C;
      }

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
    var isMobile = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('android') > -1) ||
      (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad|BlackBerry|Windows Phone|iemobile)/));
    if (isMobile) {
      var viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
      viewport.setAttribute('content', 'initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes');
    }
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('googft-mapCanvas');
    mapDiv.style.width = isMobile ? '100%' : '1200px';
    mapDiv.style.height = isMobile ? '100%' : '700px';
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.01756197213789, -87.83972673890003),
      zoom: 14,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var bikeLayer = new google.maps.BicyclingLayer();
        bikeLayer.setMap(map);

    layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      map: map,
      heatmap: { enabled: false },
      query: {
        select: "col0",
        from: "1AWcQnoMMk4kJC3qL2p_9BiYm3ZCpbDE6bh0Fmq7V",
        where: ""
      },
      options: {
        styleId: 2,
        templateId: 2
      }
    });


// Create the legend and display on the map
var legend = document.createElement('div');
        legend.id = 'legend';
        var content = [];
        content.push('<h3>Type Of Accident</h3>');
        content.push('<p><div class="color green"></div>Pedestrian</p>');
        content.push('<p><div class="color blue"></div>Pedalcyclist</p>');
        legend.innerHTML = content.join('');
        legend.index = 1;
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(legend);
      }



  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="googft-mapCanvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```